# React - Error importing dynamic images/image paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, create-react-app

So I am using create react app for my project. All my images are in the src folder. I have a json file with the image paths. I imported the json to read the paths and import the images but it's throwing a module not found error.

```
//the below import statement works perfectly for the same file yet when 
//getting it through require, it throws the module not found error
import lens from "../../assets/images/magnyfying-glass.png";
let data = require("./solodata.json");
//the above data is passed as props to the below component
function ShowcaseRow(props) {
  const printItems = () => {
    let arr = [];
    props.data.forEach((item) => {
    let pic = require(item.src).default;
      arr.push(
        <div key={item.title} className={style.package}>
          <img src={pic} />
          <div className={style.bottomContainer}>
            <div className={style.title}></div>
            <div className={style.price}></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return arr;
  };
  return (
    <div className={style.rowContainer}>
      <div className={style.row}>{printItems()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Error]

Project structure:
[image: structure]

json:
[image]

Comment: Try directly import the image for making sure the path is correct

Comment: yeah the path is correct. I have checked multiple times to make sure

Comment: Try this - `<img src={require(''+url)} />`

Comment: I have created a sample code - https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-sea-iie6w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it's working in the sandbox you shared but not working in my project :(

Comment: @SarunUK I have made an edit in the question where I am importing the same file manually also and that is working fine but for some reason using require it throws module not found error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225016/discussion-between-sarun-uk-and-goku-africa).